# Angular 10 ng-content projection causes form freeze

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular10

I got the following HTML of a component named "view-container":

[app-view-container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfC3D.png)

And now I want to place my form into this component.
Form just got 2 simple fields:

[inserted login-form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDh5D.png)

The Form shall be placed into the component via ng-content:

[content projection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VW1oO.png)

But the Problem is: This process causes the form-fields to freeze.
Y?

Answer (score 0):

Ahh nvm, community, working hard for my idiot diploma.
Not an ng-content issue:
The Form Field's Container got a position relative with z-index -1.
That actually caused the problem... solved now :>